# amazon ses mails spam in hotmail

Tags: amazon-ses

I recently set up my amazon ses. and I have a verified DKIM and have published the SPF and senderid record from my DNS. When I send a sample mail from management console of SES the mail landed in the SPAM of hotmail.infact it is a verified sender as I am still in sandbox. I could not get much help from aws team either..

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen hotmail put an email in the spam folder when the html is malformed. Make sure your html is valid, and there are no unclosed tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Amazon SES issue. You have to check with Microsoft why their Hotmail spam filters classify your domain email as junk. Note that they might also be looking at the content of the message and classify it as junk based not on the sender, but on what the body contains.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon also has intermittent issues with blacklisting. It would be wise to check the SES forums to make sure that all is well with the SES IP you are sending from and that your email itself is not on a blacklist

Check the SES forums here
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=90